# changing string to datetime in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a dataframe with the following columns:

```
       0           Pressure [bar] Temperature [C]   
0   13:07:46.380:   30.0911         11.8    
1   13:07:47.332:   30.0940         11.8    
2   13:07:50.998:   30.0911         11.8
```

I want to convert the first column to a proper datetime, so I've tried:

```
df2['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df2[0],format='%H:%M:%S.%f:')
```

But the result I got was:

```
    0           Pressure [bar]  Temperature [C] Time
0   13:07:46.380:   30.0911     11.8      1900-01-01 13:07:46.380
1   13:07:47.332:   30.0940     11.8      1900-01-01 13:07:47.332
2   13:07:50.998:   30.0911     11.8      1900-01-01 13:07:50.998
```

Which is obviously not what I wanted, I want it to be just the time, meaning:

```
 Pressure [bar] Temperature [C]     Time
0       30.0911     11.8      13:07:46.380
1       30.0940     11.8      13:07:47.332
2       30.0911     11.8      13:07:50.998
```

And using the Time column as an index.

Any ideas?

Thank you!

Comment: did you try changing the format? pd.to_datetime(df2[0],format='%H:%M:%S') will give you hours, mins and seconds. If you want a unix timestamp use https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_timestamp.html

Comment: What does "proper datetime" mean in this context? You should show us how you want your result to look in an edit.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try:

```
  df2['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['Time']).dt.time
```

Comment: Okay, I've edited your comment df2[0] to df2['Time'] and now it works!